# Intermittent Behavior Where Mails Are Sent By DocuSign According To Logs, But Not Received

Tags: docusignapi

Issue has been observed for different email boxes ( @sap and @gmail) intermittently in the DocuSign demo account.

Reproduced following cases: accoring to the envelope's history email was sent, but it hasn't been received:

1. Haven't received initial email with link navigating to the envelope;
2. Haven't received completion email.

After clinking on "Remind" button from envelope's page in the DocuSign account, email is received successfully.

We haven't received any error. Envelopes were sent without any issues. However, some recipients haven't received DocuSign email with a link to the envelope's signature page immediately. **We checked these mailboxes next day and found that emails were delivered after six hours**.

Could you clarify whether this case is expected behavior of the DocuSign? How often this might happen?

Thank you.

Comment: It happened in my case too..

Comment: We applied following workaround.

In our application we show button “Resend Email” calling
PUT /envelopes/{0}?resend_envelope=true
This request forces sending envelope notifications on demand.

Answer (score 1):

Here's some general info if/when you see intermittent or temporary issues with any part of DocuSign's service (including email delivery).  Do note, though, that DocuSign has completely separate systems with their Demo environment vs Production.

1. Check the **DocuSign Trust Center** and System Status pages:

   - https://trust.docusign.com/en-us/
   - https://trust.docusign.com/en-us/system-status/
2. Check with your DocuSign Account Manager or Professional Services.

   - For customers and partners that have an Account Manager or Professional Services engagement you can always reach out to them.
3. Check here, on Stack Overflow, to see if it's a wide-spread, well-known issue or newly discovered

---

---

Here's some more general information:

The **DEMO** environment is where your developer sandbox operates in and the API endpoints all start with

- https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/

You can test your eSignature API integration in Demo (the transactions are not legally-binding) and you can test what features you want to include before purchasing.

And lastly, DocuSign's production servers use the following URLs:

- https://www.docusign.net/restapi/
- https://na2.docusign.net/restapi/
- https://eu.docusign.net/restapi/
- https://eu1.docusign.net/restapi/